# ctrl + pgdn doesn't work with ssh

Tags: key-bindings, ssh, remote

my `.emacs.d/init.el` has this :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<prior>")  'backward-page)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<next>")  'forward-page)
```

It works fine on my machine but when I ssh to a remote host from the terminal and run emacs remotely, it seems that hitting the keys doesn't send anything to it.

For eg., if I do
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>
+
<kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>k</kbd>
then
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>
+
<kbd>pgdn</kbd>, the mode-line doesn't change, even if I repeat the keystrokes 3 times.

Comment: How are you trying it on a remote host? Through `tramp`? Or by `ssh`ing to the remote on the command line and starting an Emacs there? Or some other way? Please edit the question and add all relevant information to it.

Comment: @NickD, thanks for the clarification request. I connect via ssh then run emacs remotely, not through tramp from local emacs.

Comment: What terminal program are you using, and what does it say when you're ssh'd in to the remote system and run `echo $TERM`?  (You might be able to fix things with some terminfo settings.)

Comment: Thanks @g-gundam, as pointed out by jbe on #emacs on IRC, it was a terminal problem (konsole), which intercepts the keyboard shortcut. Trying same shortcut on xterm works fine. konsole uses the shortcut to switch tabs.

Comment: @g-gundam if you post that as a solution I will accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Keybinding Conflicts

In this specific case, `konsole` was being used as a terminal, and it had already bound <kbd>Ctrl-PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-PgDn</kbd> to switch tabs.  Thus, `konsole` intercepted those keys before Emacs could see it.  This problem was solved by using another terminal `xterm` that didn't bind those keys.